# Does Monotouch do graphics?

Tags: graphics, xamarin.ios

I want to draw squares, triangles and rectangles on my view, then take photos and put them in the squares, rectangles, etc.  I then want to be able to re-order the squares, rectangles, etc.

Is this possible in Monotouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

Here's an example of such drawing in practice: http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/drawing-with-coregraphics-in-monotouch-2/

Comment: Thank you so much... saved me a lot of hunting! :D